# Adding a Control to MVC5 Layout Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My requirement is that I want a Dropdown at the top header of my MVC5 Application, which will change the connection string used in whole application. What I want for this is a Dropdown in shared _Layout page so that if user change value in that Dropdown whole application refreshes and new connection string is used.

If this is possible then in which controller should I mention the Dropdown filling logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filling select's options you can use this structure:

```
@Html.Action("GetSelectOptions", "SomeController")
```

Where GetSelectOptions is controller action that return html with options or partial view for example. This action you can access from any layout.

The simplest way to process user choise it is to set select's onchange event with javascript function and do post from it to some your action:

```
$.post("/set-connection-string", { connectionString: "get value from select here" });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Rather using a controller, I created a Static class and filled my Dropdown using that class.